# Exporting TypeScript settings in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, settings, webstorm

Can TypeScript settings in WebStorm be exported? I mean these settings:

[image]

Couldn't find them in `File > Export Setting...` window

Comment: Well, you can simply use a `tsconfig.json` file and then you can even use that with other tools other than webstorm

Comment: It's not about typescript settings, but typescript settings in WebStorm - Having TypeScript Compiler enabled etc

Comment: As you can see this settings page has "For current project" label -- such setting is not exported via `File | Export Settings...` because it's a part of the current project settings .. and stored in one of the files in `.idea` subfolder in your project root.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to .idea. What you are saying is not entirely true, though. Look at File Watchers, they are project specific, but exportable still (though not through File | Export Settings...)

Comment: Ok. So I set up TypeScript settings in WebStorm. After that, a file called typescript-compiler.xml was created in .idea folder. XML can be easily copied and pasted in someone else's .idea directory. For me, it worked like a charm :)